# Confusion on a simple logarithm rule

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, hyperbolic-functions

I am confident with

$$A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C
= \frac{A+B}{2} e^{\alpha x} (1-pe^{-\alpha x}) (1-qe^{-\alpha x}).$$

where $p$ and $q$ are solutions of the equation $ \frac{A+B}{2}t^2 + Ct + \frac{A-B}{2} = 0$.

I assumed that taking natural $\log$ (i.e. ln) yields:

\begin{align*}
&\log\left(A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C\right) \\
&\hspace{6em}= \log(\frac{A+B}{2}) + \alpha x + \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x}) + \log(1-qe^{-\alpha x}).
\end{align*}

However, [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log((%20((A%2BB)%2F2)*e%5E(a*x)*(1-e%5E(-a*x)*p)%20*(1-e%5E(-a*x)*q)))) says:

\begin{align*}
&\log\left(A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C\right) \\
&\hspace{6em}= 2i\pi\lfloor(\frac{-(\arg(1-pe^{-ax})+\arg(1-qe^{-ax})-\pi)}{2\pi})\rfloor\\
&\hspace{6em}+\log(\frac{A+B}{2}) + \alpha x + \log(1-pe^{-\alpha x}) + \log(1-qe^{-\alpha x}).
\end{align*}

Can someone please explain the appearance of those args. I do not get it.

PS: More confusion comes from the fact that the quantity that I'm measuring (i.e. $F(x)=A\cosh(\alpha x) + B\sinh(\alpha x) + C$) is all real, so having imaginary part in $\log$ result does not seem right to me at all.

Comment: $1-pe^{-\alpha x}$ and $1-qe^{-\alpha x}$ might be negative.

Comment: Worse, they might be complex (as far as Wolfram knows).  So to get Wolfram to yield your answer, you need to tell it more information.

Comment: @GEdgar $A$, $B$, $C$ and $\alpha$ are all real. That's all I know. Can you please elaborate how it could affect.

Comment: Unless you tell Wolfram, it does not know $A,B,C$ are real.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you please let me how to do it here: [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log((+((A%2BB)%2F2)*e%5E(a*x)*(1-e%5E(-a*x)*p)+*(1-e%5E(-a*x)*q)))) I do not know how to enforce that $A$, $B$, $\alpha$, $p$ and $q$ are real.